# How to find examples of matrices $A$ such that $AA^T$ equals a given matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices

I want to find examples of square matrices $A$ (and if possible, a general form) which satisfy the following property:

$$AA^{T} = \frac{1}{4} \left[\begin{matrix}
    15 & 9 & 5 & -3 \\
    9 & 15 & 3 & -5 \\
    5 & 3 & 15 & -9 \\
    -3 & -5 & -9 & 15
  \end{matrix}\right]$$

What would a systematic way to go about this?

P.S: The matrix on the right hand side is Hermitian.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since $B=AA^T$ is symmetric, by eigenvalues and eigenvectors, we can find $Q$ orthogonal and $\Lambda$ diagonal such that

$$B=Q\Lambda Q^T$$

and if $B$ is positive definite we have

$$B=Q\Lambda Q^T=(Q\Lambda^{1/2})(Q\Lambda^{1/2})^T=AA^T$$

Comment: And how to find such $Q$?

Comment: @Blue $Q$ is the orthogonal matrix containing an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors as columns

Comment: @Blue refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_matrix#Decomposition

Comment: @Blue refer also to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cholesky_decomposition

Comment: @Blue This is the orthogonal diagonalisation of $B$, which are guaranteed to exist for symmetric matrices. You find them ususally by eigenvalue / eigenvector analysis. You do have to make sure that $B$ is positive semi-definite, though, or at least that it has an even number of negative eigenvalues or something. Otherwise $\Lambda^{1/2}$ is going to be a bit tricky.

Comment: @Arthur Yes of course, I add that point. Thanks

Comment: @WillJagy I didn't refer to that specific case and to the best way to digonalize the matrix in taht case. Your contribution is always intresting and useful. Thanks

Comment: bit of trickery, there is a slightly disguised block decomposition, all can be done by hand, the eigenvalues are $1,2,4,8.$

Answer (score 4):

You would want this version:

$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
15 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 48 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 40 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 128 }{ 15 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
15 & 9 & 5 &  - 3 \\ 
9 & 15 & 3 &  - 5 \\ 
5 & 3 & 15 &  - 9 \\ 
 - 3 &  - 5 &  - 9 & 15 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Since $D$ is positive definite, create a matrix $F$  with entries $\sqrt d$ to get  $Q^T F^T F Q = (FQ)^T (FQ) = H$ after deleting the $D.$ Let's see, you had a factor of $1/4,$ so $  (FQ/2)^T (FQ/2) = H/4$

Algorithm discussed at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1388421/reference-for-linear-algebra-books-that-teach-reverse-hermite-method-for-symmetr
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester%27s_law_of_inertia
$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
15 & 9 & 5 &  - 3 \\ 
9 & 15 & 3 &  - 5 \\ 
5 & 3 & 15 &  - 9 \\ 
 - 3 &  - 5 &  - 9 & 15 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  D_0 = H  $$
$$ E_j^T D_{j-1} E_j = D_j  $$
$$  P_{j-1} E_j = P_j  $$
$$ E_j^{-1} Q_{j-1}  = Q_j  $$
$$  P_j Q_j = Q_j P_j = I  $$
$$ P_j^T H P_j = D_j  $$
$$ Q_j^T D_j Q_j = H  $$

$$ H = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
15 & 9 & 5 &  - 3 \\ 
9 & 15 & 3 &  - 5 \\ 
5 & 3 & 15 &  - 9 \\ 
 - 3 &  - 5 &  - 9 & 15 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{1} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
15 & 0 & 5 &  - 3 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 48 }{ 5 }  & 0 &  -  \frac{ 16 }{ 5 }  \\ 
5 & 0 & 15 &  - 9 \\ 
 - 3 &  -  \frac{ 16 }{ 5 }  &  - 9 & 15 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{2} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
15 & 0 & 0 &  - 3 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 48 }{ 5 }  & 0 &  -  \frac{ 16 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 40 }{ 3 }  &  - 8 \\ 
 - 3 &  -  \frac{ 16 }{ 5 }  &  - 8 & 15 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{3} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
15 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 48 }{ 5 }  & 0 &  -  \frac{ 16 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 40 }{ 3 }  &  - 8 \\ 
0 &  -  \frac{ 16 }{ 5 }  &  - 8 &  \frac{ 72 }{ 5 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{4} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
15 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 48 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 40 }{ 3 }  &  - 8 \\ 
0 & 0 &  - 8 &  \frac{ 40 }{ 3 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ E_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$  P_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; Q_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
, \; \; \; D_{5} = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
15 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 48 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 40 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 128 }{ 15 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

==============================================

$$ P^T H P = D  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
15 & 9 & 5 &  - 3 \\ 
9 & 15 & 3 &  - 5 \\ 
5 & 3 & 15 &  - 9 \\ 
 - 3 &  - 5 &  - 9 & 15 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
15 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 48 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 40 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 128 }{ 15 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$
$$ Q^T D Q = H  $$
$$\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
 \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  & 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 
 -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
15 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 &  \frac{ 48 }{ 5 }  & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 &  \frac{ 40 }{ 3 }  & 0 \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 &  \frac{ 128 }{ 15 }  \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
\left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
1 &  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  &  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 &  -  \frac{ 1 }{ 3 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 1 &  -  \frac{ 3 }{ 5 }  \\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
 = \left( 
\begin{array}{rrrr} 
15 & 9 & 5 &  - 3 \\ 
9 & 15 & 3 &  - 5 \\ 
5 & 3 & 15 &  - 9 \\ 
 - 3 &  - 5 &  - 9 & 15 \\ 
\end{array}
\right) 
$$

Answer (score 3):

Looking again, this seems to be a contest type question. With a little trickery, one may find the eigenvalues entirely by hand, without attempting any 4 by 4 determinant.  MORE TO COME

First, multiply by $4,$ the fraction can be dealt with later. Next, multiply one left and right by the orthogonal matrix (its own transpose)
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 
\end{array}
\right)
$$

The result is a matrix in 2 by 2 blocks,
$$
M =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
3A & A \\
A & 3A
\end{array}
\right)
$$
where
$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
5 & 3 \\
3 & 5
\end{array}
\right)
$$
The eigenvalues of this are $2,8.$ We can construct eigenvectors for the 4 by 4 $M$ above with no trouble. If $v$ has eigenvalue $2,$ then
as eigenvectors for my $M$ above,
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
v \\
v
\end{array}
\right)
$$
has eigenvalue $8$ while
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
v \\
-v
\end{array}
\right)
$$
has eigenvalue $4.$ 
If $w$ has eigenvalue $8,$ then
as eigenvectors for my $M$ above,
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
w \\
w
\end{array}
\right)
$$
has eigenvalue $32$ while
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
w \\
-w
\end{array}
\right)
$$
has eigenvalue $16.$

So, my $M$ has eigenvalues $4,8,16,32.$  One may use the $M$ eigenvectors to reconstruct eigenvectors for the original matrix, or start over. Including the $1/4$ fraction, the matrix in the question has eigenvalues $1,2,4,8.$